# trying to split Strings in Java that are scanned from user

Tags: java, methods

I'm building a project where I will take three inputs from the users: name,ID,GPA. the users should enter them in one line separated by a semicolumn";" and I want to be able to receive them as one line and be able to save them in three variables. 
I'm applying a method where I will take three variables from the user. for example : the user will enter the name,Id and GPA like this:

```
1;Sally;90.5;       //in one line separated by ";"
```

I want to be able to save each info from the user in different variable.
Can someone tell me how will I be able to implement that?

Here is the method:

```
private static void addNewStudent() {
    System.out.println("enter ID;Name;Gpa; ");
    String info = scanner.nextLine();
```

Note: I'm trying the apply the CSV in my project.

Comment: What is the line delimiter? is it ";" , or ","

Comment: It should be like this ;

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You just need read one line and then split it into string array.The input order must be ID -> NAME -> GPA:

```
    private static void addNewStudent() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter ID;Name;Gpa; ");
        String info = scanner.nextLine();
        if (info != null) {
            String[] infoArray = info.split(",");
            if (infoArray.length == 3) {
                String id = infoArray[0];
                String name = infoArray[1];
                String gpa = infoArray[2];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answers the question. 

But keep in mind @sally you probably do not want to store id or gpa as a string. :)

Comment: yes,id may store a string,but jpa may store as `double`

Answer (score 0):

This should do to split the input by ";":

```
String[] input = GPA.split[";"];
```

Before trying to get the values, check if the input array has the expected size.

Comment: how will I be able to save them in different variables If I did this

Comment: Input will be a String array. You access the values by:
input[0] // first value
input[1] // second value
....